# Play framework - custom authentication

Tags: playframework

I have tried the tutorial about Security module for Play! 1.2.3.
The authentication mechanism is pretty straightforward and simple.

I have a question. If i want to implement a custom authentication, is it possible to customize security module, or i have to write the code from scratch?

For example, i want to authenticate by request header parameter, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Secure module is tiny : you can get all the code from this module, put it in your application and customize it as you want

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a bigger thing you can write an Plugin. You can see an example at my [permsec-module](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~opensource21/+junk/permsec/files), which is unfortunately still under construction, but should contain everything you need. See specially [PsecPlugin](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~opensource21/+junk/permsec/view/head:/psec/app/psec/PsecPlugin.java).

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that for basic auth in your controller using the `@Before` annotation. Then in the request method just check if the account argument is set.

```java
@Before
static void checkAuth() {    
  // Get auth header
  Header auth = request.headers.get("authorization");
  if (auth == null) return;

  // Get basic auth value
  String authValue = auth.value();
  if (authValue == null) return;

  // Split header components
  String[] authComp = authValue.split(" ");
  if (authComp.length != 2) return;

  // Decode base64 auth string
  String basic = new String(Codec.decodeBASE64(authComp[1]));
  String[] userPass = basic.split(":");
  if (userPass.length != 2) return;

  // Try to fetch account
  String email = userPass[0];
  String pass = userPass[1];
  String passSHA1 = Codec.hexSHA1(pass);

  List<models.Account> accounts = models.Account.find("email password", email,     passSHA1).asList();
  if (accounts.size() != 1) return;

  // Set account on request
  request.args.put("_authenticatedUser", accounts.get(0));
}
```